# Prestashop 1.7.3.3 Edit Registration Form

Tags: prestashop

I use prestashop 1.7.3.3 e-commerce system. 
I need to get a phone number from the customer. 
Phone field looks optional. I want to make it mandatory.
How can i do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAQlE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that field as mandatory in the `BO > Customers > Addresses`.

[image: example]